# Applescript, quit app if other app is quit

Tags: macos, applescript, applications, plex

I have a (very basic) apple script that I use as a trigger to start and hijack Plex, using Audio Hijack Pro.

```
tell application "Audio Hijack Pro"
start hijacking session named "Plex"
end tell
tell application "Plex"
    activate
end tell
```

Where the last three lines just ensure Plex is in the foreground.

Here is where my question comes in. If possible, I would like to extend my script a little; it should keep running while Hijack Audio Pro is hijacking Plex, and quit Hijack Audio Pro if Plex is quit. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I've only dabbled in Applescript, but would you be able to create a second script that is basically reversed? In English it would look like:

```
tell Plex to quit
then
tell Audio Hijack Pro to quit
```